# Are UV unwraps with identical settings the same every time?

Tags: texturing, uv

If I have two identical objects with the exact same geometry and seams, and I unwrap them with the same settings, will their respective UV unwraps always be identical? Or is there any randomization with UV unwrapping even with the same situation?

Comment: after some test I'd say: identical

Comment: If there was any randomness to it at all, my guess is that you wouldn't need two separate instances of your mesh just to perform a test. Presumably, one mesh would be sufficient, by repeatedly undoing the unwrap and redoing it. One would think that eventually, it would unwrap in a different way. I don't see any reason to imagine that, on the assumption that there IS randomness, we should expect to get consistent results from a single mesh being re-unwrapped over and over, but also expect to get get potentially random outcomes when applying the unwrap to different but identical meshes.

Comment: The thing is, I am using a vagon remote computer, which is a lot more powerful than mine, to bake textures and full renders onto objects, and then download the result onto my own computer, to then apply to the objects in there. Both the blender file on the vagon computer and on mine have the same geometry and seams, and I have to unwrap the same object once on vagon, and a second time on my own PC to get my desired end result. So if there's inconsistency with the unwrapping process, it can mess the result up. That's my situation.